# Enable systemd services using yocto

Tags: yocto, bitbake

Hi this is my layer tree

```
├── conf
│   └── layer.conf
├── COPYING.MIT
├── README
└── recipes-hello
    ├── helloworld
    │   ├── helloworld-0.1
    │   │   ├── helloworld.c
    │   │   ├── helloworld.patch
    │   │   └── newhelloworld.c
    │   └── helloworld_0.1.bb
    ├── message
    │   ├── message-0.1
    │   │   └── message.txt
    │   └── message_0.1.bb
    └── service
        ├── service-0.1
        │   ├── test_systemd.service
        │   └── test_systemd.sh
        └── service_0.1.bb
```

Here test_systemd.service is the service file which have to invoke test_systemd.sh, which I am trying to achieve using service_0.1.bb

```
    # This recipe performs the following tasks
    # 1) Install .sh file in /home/root/ and .sh script creates a random text file
    # 2) Install the .service file in systemd directory
    # 3) Invoke the .sh script via .service file
    inherit systemd

SUMMARY = "Install and start a systemd service"
SECTION = "examples"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"

#here we specify the source we want to build
SRC_URI = "file://test_systemd.sh"
SRC_URI += "file://test_systemd.service"
#here we specify the source directory, where we can do all the building and expect sources to be placed
S = "${WORKDIR}"

SYSTEMD_SERVICE_${PN} = "test_systemd.service"


#bitbake task
#created a directory /home/root for target install the script
do_install() {
             install -d ${D}/home/root
             install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/test_systemd.sh ${D}/home/root

             install -d ${D}{systemd_system_unitdir}
             install -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/test_systemd.service ${D}{systemd_system_unitdir}
}

#Pack the path
FILES_${PN} += "/home/root"
FILES_${PN} += "/lib/systemd/system"

REQUIRED_DISTRO_FEATURES= "systemd"
```

The problem is when I try to bitbake system recipe, bitbake throws an error saying test_systemd.service not found.
I managed to install both the files in RFS with a previous attempt but when I include the systemd concept. I get the no such file error. What could be the reason ?
Error message

```
 NOTE: Executing SetScene Tasks
NOTE: Executing RunQueue Tasks
ERROR: service-0.1-r0 do_package: SYSTEMD_SERVICE_service value test_systemd.service does not exist
ERROR: service-0.1-r0 do_package: Function failed: systemd_populate_packages
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/guest/yocto_practice/poky/build-beaglebone/tmp/work/cortexa8hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/service/0.1-r0/temp/log.do_package.2860
ERROR: Task (/home/guest/yocto_practice/meta-testlayer/recipes-hello/service/service_0.1.bb:do_package) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 514 tasks of which 506 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.

Summary: 1 task failed:
  /home/guest/yocto_practice/meta-testlayer/recipes-hello/service/service_0.1.bb:do_package
Summary: There were 2 ERROR messages shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

Also is this the correct way to write bb recipe for systemd and what is the significance of writing this

```
#Pack the path
    FILES_${PN} += "/home/root"
    FILES_${PN} += "/lib/systemd/system"
```

without this bitbake throws error.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
SYSTEMD_SERVICE_${PN} += "file://test_systemd.service"
```

This should be:

```
SYSTEMD_SERVICE_${PN} = "test_systemd.service"
```

Other notes (unrelated to the error):

- Installing things into /home is probably not a great idea (you could use e.g. `${libexecdir}` for scripts that other scripts need.
- there's no reason for having a `do_install_append()` in a bb file: you can just put everything in `do_install()`
- If your Yocto is recent, using `${systemd_system_unitdir}` instead of `/lib/systemd/system` is a good idea (in older releases `${systemd_unitdir}/system/` works)

Comment: Thanks for suggesting for mods. I did changes according to you but still getting the error. Will update the question

Comment: I still get the same error. Don't know why bitbake couldn't find the file at the location where it exists.

Comment: Your current recipe refers twice to `${D}{systemd_system_unitdir}`. It should be `${D}${systemd_system_unitdir}`. Otherwise it works here.

Comment: Thanks for the other notes, I learned something new about systemd_system_unitdir!

Answer (score 1):

In order to resolve this packaging error, I used the following install step

```
do_install() {
   install -d ${D}${bindir}
   install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/test_systemd.sh ${D}${bindir}
   install -d ${D}${systemd_unitdir}/system
   install -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/test_systemd.service ${D}${systemd_unitdir}/system
}
```